# Where is the java.security file on Android?

Tags: java, android, security, android-contentprovider

I'm using Android Commander to view the files on my Android phone. Furthermore I want to view and change "java.security" file in which security providers can be statically registered. On Linux PCs, this file is located in the directory $JAVA_HOME/lib/security but I couldn't find it on my Android device. Where's it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mabe just not possible yet - see http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=21417

Comment: Thanks but then how does the Android select the algorithms and providers when we execute an app using security classes?

Comment: Sorry, but don't know this. As even RSA is opening a case, this might be not public.

Comment: I would also be interested in an answer to this question. I noticed that the link mentioned by @mtraut shows that the raised issue is dated Oct. 31, 2011.

Comment: I am not sure if my comment above gets to you, perhaps I should have written @ mtraut