# What is "the highest-priority implementation for the TrustManagerFactory" in JSSE Reference Guide?

Tags: java, android, ssl, certificate

I am reading from https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#SSLContext about the SSLContext Class. In particular, regarding the init method:

```
public void init(KeyManager[] km, TrustManager[] tm, SecureRandom random);
```

They say that if the tm parameter is null then "... the installed security providers will be searched for the highest-priority implementation of the TrustManagerFactory, from which an appropriate TrustManager will be obtained." What is this default algorithm? (the highest priority implementation of the TrustManagerFactory). I searched the Internet and I found only this link https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYKE2_7.0.0/com.ibm.java.security.component.70.doc/security-component/jsse2Docs/pkixtrustmgrsupport.html where they mention the PKIX algorithm. I am not sure whether this is the correct answer.

Comment: "What is this default algorithm?" -- on Android, it probably varies by Android OS version.

Comment: Yes, perhaps it varies by Android OS version. I am not interested in a particular version. But I would like to know whether there is a similar java.security file on Android. And I found this relevant link which unfortunately seems to show that there is no answer yet for my question regarding the Android file. The link is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10462035/where-is-the-java-security-file-on-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It simply means the one from the security provider which is listed highest in the `java.security` file.

I don't see anything in your IBM link that addresses the issue in any way.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, @EJP. I am learning new things. Sorry for my lack of knowledge, but what is the role of the file java.security? Who creates this file?

Comment: Have a look at the `java.security.Provider` Javadoc. But chances are you don't need to know any of this.

Comment: I found that the java.security file is in the lib/security directory of the JDK or JRE. But if it is about an Android application, is it still in the JDK or JRE?

Comment: Sorry, no idea, I pass.

Comment: Ok, @EJP, your previous answer was useful. I would appreciate it very much if anybody could answer the question for an Android app in particular.